# How to crop an image to a certain aspect ratio with Cordova/Ionic?

Tags: android, ios, image, cordova, ionic-framework

When an image is cropped on mobile, normally, a user is able to adjust the size of the cropped image by dragging the "viewport" around.

I'd like to let the user resize the crop window, but only if the aspect ratio is locked: the resulting image will be stretched to fit said ratio when it is displayed.

Is there a way to do this with core Ionic or third party libraries or this something I will have to rely on ImageMagik for server-side?

For the visual learners:

[image]

Comment: i had a look around for you and found this library with many options. I never used ionic so im not sure about Jquery and Ionic working together  https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: @dsp_099 check out this link - https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine hope it helps

Comment: are you using Ionic 1 or Ionic 2?

Answer (score 1):

After some googling, have found that there is a readymade cordova plugin available for this requirement which also helps in retaining the aspect ratio.

Check out this [cordova-crop-plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop) which is active and also there is a recent fix made in this regarding aspect ratio. It also has a sample code in the README doc that works with Ionic & Angular2.

Also check this out - [Issue link](http://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop/issues/8) The aspect ratio is locked by default in android and ios's aspect ratio lock is also fixed

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: I've seen this plugin also, however the API only lists "quality" as a parameter... how does one "lock" the aspect ratio? I see the latest commit involves a line like `+    cropController.keepingCropAspectRatio = YES;` but how is that actually used?

Comment: @dsp_099 Check this out - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop/issues/8 The aspect ratio is locked by default in android and ios's aspect ratio lock is also fixed. You can refer more on the follow link - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop/blob/master/src/ios/CTCrop.m#L36-L44 as suggested by the plugin's author

Comment: @dsp_099 did you cracked it?

Comment: The ionic philosophy is to not write/edit any line of Native Code. It's too bad we cannot just set the aspect ratio in the option variable.